# Find object by properties from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

With an array, a value, and and an object with nested objects:

**Object**

```
mesh
```

**Array**

```
['options', 'range', 'x']
```

**Value**

```
12.5
```

Is it possible to translate this to update a property, e.g.

```
mesh.options.range.x = 12.5
```

**Attempted:**

```
index = (obj, i) ->
   obj[i]

arr.reduce(index, obj) = 12.5
```

**Update**

Thank you all for the elegant solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by "*translate*"?

Comment: Ohh - we wants to loop the array and add properties to the object.  Ok.  WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to convert the contents of an array to an object and then set it to the value?

Comment: Convert it to an assignment

Comment: you can make a simple resolve() utility using [].reduce()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.reduce()` is actually pretty nice for this:

```
// current object----|    |----current key
//                   v    v
arr.reduce(function(obj, key) {
    return obj == null ? obj : obj[key];
}, window.mesh);
//        ^
//        |-- initial object
```

---

Your attempt to use `.reduce()`  needed to pass a function that manages the "accumulation".

Here, as long as the previous `obj` wasn't `null` or `undefined`, it'll return the `key` of the current `obj`, which becomes the next `obj`.

---

Then since you need to assign a value, you'd actually want to get the value of the second to last key.

```
var o = arr.slice(0,-1).reduce(function(obj, key) {
    return obj == null ? obj : obj[key];
}, window.mesh);
```

And then check its existence and use the last item in `arr` to do the assignment.

```
o && o[arr.pop()] = 12.5;
```

---

All of this can be abstracted away into a function that does one or the other based on how many arguments were passed.

```
function setFromArray(obj, arr, val) {
    var keys = arguments.length < 3 ? arr.slice() : arr.slice(0, -1);

    var o = keys.slice(0,-1).reduce(function(obj, key) {
        return obj == null ? obj : obj[key];
    }, window.mesh);

    if (arguments.length < 3)
        return o;
    else 
        o && o[keys.pop()];
}
```

Comment: Nice. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around which solution is better vs. Jake's -- performing the assignment inside vs. externally

Comment: @TaylorMac: I think it doesn't really make much difference. Mostly just a personal preference. His solution is good too. As long as the approach is abstracted away into a function, it'll be clean.

Comment: ...one change he may want to make would be to make sure that each item in the path produces an object for the next iteration. Otherwise the program could fail with a TypeError.

Comment: Just tested. Thank you mr. cookie monster

Comment: @TaylorMac: You're welcome. And I just noticed that in my last two examples, I forgot to type `[key]`, so that's fixed now. You probably figured that out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general solution:

```
function setPropertyPath(obj, path, value) {
    var o = obj;
    for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
        o = o[path[i]];
    }
    o[path[path.length - 1]] = value;
}
```

Usage:

```
var obj = { a: { b: { c: 0 } } };
setPropertyPath(obj, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 10);
console.log(obj.a.b.c); // prints '10'
```

[**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/qibopada/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Thank you for handling the assignment

Answer (score 0):

```
var mesh = {},
    arr = ['options','range','x'],
    value = 12.5;

mesh[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If array length is static do something like this:

```
mesh[array[0]][array[1]][array[2]] = value;
```

However, one problem with this is that javascript doesn't do autovivification, so if you're accessing a key value that isn't previously defined you could run into errors (if mesh.options hasn't been defined then the above will throw an error because you can't assign to it).  To solve that you might abstract this out into a function that handles things recursively:

http://jsfiddle.net/h4jVg/

```
function update_val(obj, array, val, prev) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        obj = val;
        return;
    }

    var cur = array.shift();

    if(array.length == 0) {
        obj[cur] = val;
        return;
    } else if (obj[cur] == undefined) {
        obj[cur] = {};
    }

    update_val(obj[cur], array, val);
}
```

Comment: Also a great recursive solution. Wondering how this performs compares to Jake King & cookie monster